# why does kernel send a tlb invalidate interrupt to all other processors,when the page table modified is personal to the process running

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, tlb, multiprocessor

when a a page table entry of one process, the kernel thread issues tlb shootdown interrupt to all other processors to invalidate the tlbs on other processors? But, is it not that, the page table is specific to this process, why should we go for a tlb shoot down?

Answer (score 6):

Your process may have multiple threads, which all share the same page table, and they may be executing in different processors.

Comment: Shootdown is required even if there is only one thread because the process may have moved between cores/processors.  The OS can keep track of this and only send shootdowns to the cores on which that process has lived in the past.  Essentially, it is implementing cache coherence in software.